# Google Cloud Translation Api returns only translation in target language

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit, google-translation-api

I have implemented Google Cloud Translation API to translate English to the Kannada language. It is working fine, however, when I call

```
translation.getTranslatedText();
```

I receive the only translation in Target language script. I would like to display it in both English and the target language. Could somebody please help me how to do it?

Comment: What do u mean? You already have the English word, which you are translating from. So you have the source, and you get the target translation from `getTranslatedText()`. What else do u need?

Comment: I need the transliteration. I would like to show Kannada translation in English. Otherwise how would a person who doesn't know Kannada will read it?.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Translation API like in [this](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text) example which prints the source text and detected source language along with the translation.

Comment: I have already done it. You may need to go through the question again please.

Comment: You'd like to receive both the source text and translated text right? You have the source text in "result['input']" and the translation inside the "result['translatedText']"

Comment: [getTranslatedText](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/translate/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/translate/model/TranslationsResource.html#getTranslatedText()) returns only the translated text.

Comment: Yes. I am looking for the translation written in english. The same one we can find it on Google Translator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option both in the [Translate API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/translate/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/translate/model/TranslationsResource.html) and the corresponding [Java API interface documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate).